# Conversion of Video for Testing CNN-LSTM (Vgg16) model

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm, video-processing, data-preprocessing

I'm facing an issue to test my CNN-LSTM model whose input is (None,20,4096) and the video preprocessing techniques generate some different input Eg :(1,244,244,3)

I tried multiple preprocessing algorithm/technique which result into similar input array

def preprocess_frame(frame):
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (4096,20))
frame = frame/255.0
return frame

def predict_violence(video_path):
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

```
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Couldn't open video file.")
    return

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break  

    preprocessed_frame = preprocess_frame(frame)

    input_data = np.expand_dims(preprocessed_frame, axis=0)
    
    input_data = np.expand_dims(input_data, axis=0)

    prediction = model.predict(input_data)


    violence_prediction = (prediction > 0.5).astype(int)

    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    print("Violence Prediction:", violence_prediction[0][0])

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

video_path = 'path'
predict_violence(video_path)